# IllegalStateException while using Tables in android

Tags: java, android

When I execute the following code I get an IllegalStateException..

```
public class DatabaseView extends Activity{
 TextView tv;
 MySQLiteHelper h;
 TableLayout main;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newview);
    h=new MySQLiteHelper(this);
    main=(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tb1);

    table();

}
private void table() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
TableRow header_row=new TableRow(this); 
header_row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView item=new TextView(this);
item.setText("Item");
header_row.addView(item);

TextView amt=new TextView(this);
amt.setText("Amount");
header_row.addView(amt);
main.addView(header_row, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
Cursor c=h.getAllEntry();
c.moveToFirst();
do

{
TableRow tr=new TableRow(this); 
tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
TextView tv=new TextView(this);
Log.d(" ", c.getString(2));
tv.setText(c.getString(2));
tr.addView(item);

TextView amnt=new TextView(this);
Log.d(" ", c.getString(1));
amnt.setText(c.getString(1));
tr.addView(amt);    

tr.addView(tv);
tr.addView(amnt);
main.addView(tr,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
c.moveToNext();
}while(!c.isAfterLast());

}
```

The error log is--

---

> AndroidRuntime(1692):FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   AndroidRuntime(1692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.expensesdatabase/com.example.expensesdatabase.DatabaseView}: >java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   AndroidRuntime(1692):at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

---

Please tell why this error is occurring and solution to the same.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the do-while loop, you're re-adding `item` and `amt` views that you've already added to a parent.

Errors like this are easy to diagnose when you look at the logcat, below the part you've posted. There's a "caused by" exception below it that points you to the exact line of code.